# Installing python >= 3.6 in Ubuntu pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, terminal, pip

I am new to ***virtual env wrapper*** and had been using ***anaconda virtual env** before.I am trying to update my python version to >= 3.7, but I am unable to install it using ***pip***. Please help me updating the python to the required version inside the ***virtual environment wrapper***.

I have tried `pip install -U python` and `pip install python>=3.7` as I would do in ***anaconda** but it does not work.

Using the method mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv/39713544#39713544) I get the following error.

[image]

Comment: Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv/39713544#39713544

Comment: Both the methods are not working for me. I am already on 3.5.2 and even after following them getting the same version. Could you elaborate if possible?